# Generated Bitmap has only zero values

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I'm trying to decode a byte array into a bitmap to be used in android.
The byte array that i use for decoding is generated by an OpenGl conmmand named GlReadPixels and the data inside is correct.

```
    MainActivity.dataInputStream.readFully(Image, 0,256 * 256 * 4);

//converting from rgba to argb
    for (int i = 0; i < Image.length - 1; i = i + 4) {
        aux = (Image[i + 3] & 0xFF);
    IntImage[i + 3] = (int) (Image[i + 2] & 0xFF);
    IntImage[i + 2] = (int) (Image[i + 1] & 0xFF);
    IntImage[i + 1] = (int) (Image[i] & 0xFF);
    IntImage[i] = aux;
     }
```

if i do this :`bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(IntImage, 256, 256,Config.ARGB_8888);` or this:

`bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(256, 256, Config.ARGB_8888);
bmp.setPixels(IntImage, 0, 256, 0, 0, 256, 256);` ,

the resulted bitmap will have only 0 values.

Can somebody please tell me why that is  ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bitmap.createBitmap is expecting array of 256*256 size, and you are giving it 256*256*4, and therefore you are giving one part only and it looks like this, 0x000000FF .. 0x000000RR, 0x000000GG, if you understand what I mean.

change your argb function in something like this

```
int[] imageARGB = new int[256 * 256];

for(int i = 0; i < imageARGB.length, i++){
    imageARGB[i] = Color.argb(yourAlpha, RR, GG, BB);
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you! This worked. I've been struggeling with this for the past 3-4 days.